# Problems with route table with two nics on different subnets

Tags: ubuntu, routing, linux-networking

I have an Ubuntu server with two NICs on two different vlans. Both nics are able to reach the internet. The server is an Ubuntu MAAS machine and therefore has pxe and dhcp and such. The DHCP server for the 172.20.0.0/16 network is the server itself.

- Nic 1: 172.20.0.1/16       gw: 172.20.0.11   Vlan 56
- Nic 2: 172.16.254.254/16   gw: 172.16.0.11   Vlan 1

**The problem:**
A client on vlan 56 can ping 172.20.0.1 and any address on vlan 1 except 172.16.254.254 (the address of the other nic of the server).

A client on vlan 1 can ping any machine on vlan 56 except 172.20.0.1
If I mess with the routes I can get one interface to work or the other but never both. What should my routing table look like?

**Firewall Rules (iptable -L -n):**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: What does your firewall look like (`iptables -L -n`)? Perhaps your FORWARD rules allows all, but your INPUT rules do not.

Comment: I added the firewall rules.